# MySQL select count of another table's rows where the IDs match

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select from one table with the count of another table where the id matches the original tableID sort of like:

```
select *, (count(0) from table2 where table2.table1ID = table1.table1ID) count
    from table1
```

What's the mySQL syntax for this?

Comment: Try `(select count(*) from table2 ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  table1.*,
  if(table2.table1ID is null,0,count(*))
from
  table1
  left join table2 on table1.table1ID = table2.table1ID
group by
  table1.table1ID;
```

Comment: When I do this and there are no matches in table2 (ie. count should be 0), I get a count of 1

Comment: Ah, I see. So in order to get those zeros I guess you changed my join to a left join. I've kept the left join and added an if flow control statement to the select. Can't think of any other way of keeping the columns you want to have a count of zero and making them zero, apart from a union, which would make the query much bigger and probably slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(b.*) FROM table1 as a
LEFT JOIN table2 as b ON a.tableID = b.tableID
```